# Azure AD B2C - no option to login by normal account, but there is for external

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I added to my Azure AD B2C option to log in by an external provider - [Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-oidc-azure-active-directory) from my other tenant. Now I try to sign in by following accounts:

[image]

What is extremely strange, that I can sign in by external account but with 'normal' account I get:

User account 'rmaziarka@radekmaziarka.onmicrosoft.com' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/****/' does not exist in tenant 'Guests users' and cannot access the application '2e7e5a25-1755-43f6-be9b-76203b654abe'(Auth0) in that tenant. **The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.**

Why is that? Why I can sign in by invited one, but I cannot by a normal user? I have a tenant with 400 employees. Should I create another tenant and invite all users there?

Comment: Can you make this Azure AD identity provider a multi-tenant? That would allow you to login with users from both of your tenants.

Comment: @TiagoBrenck you mean by that policy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-commonaad-custom ?

Comment: Yes. I have it set up and I can login with users from many AAD tenants on my B2C tenant (and of course all the B2C users as well).

Answer (score 0):

If you add A tenant as an external provider, the users from A tenant will be able to login. The users from your B2C tenant is recognized as local users, so you need to add Local Account to the identity provider.

[image]

Login in your external ad users with social account and login in your b2c tenant users with local account.

[image]

Comment: There is an option to sign in into this tenant by OpenID:https://i.imgur.com/am8dQfh.png
- rmaziarka@radsoft.com can sign in
- rmaziarka@radekmaziarka.onmicrosoft.com cannot sign in

Comment: @RadosławMaziarka Yes, have you selected both local account and openId Connect as the identity provider?

Comment: @RadosławMaziarka rmaziarka@radsoft.com is external tenant user and maziarka@radekmaziarka.onmicrosoft.com is your b2c tenant user, right?

Comment: I have 2 different tenants: Azure AD and Azure AD B2C. I try to login by B2C from Azure AD. In Azure AD I have 2 users - @ radekmaziarka.onmicrosoft.com is native to Azure AD and @ radsoft.com was invited from some other tenant (let's say that's third tenant.).

Comment: Yes, I selected both options.

Comment: @RadosławMaziarka For Azure AD users, you need to login in as social account, for the users under azure ad b2c tenant, you need to login in as local account.